# Perl MongoDb multiple update

Tags: perl, mongodb

i want to update all records in my database(mongodb),I tried to use command below to do that 
but I could not reach the solution.

```
use MongoDB;
my $dbhost = MongoDB::Connection->new(host => '127.0.0.1', port => 27017);
    my $database   = $dbhost->test;
my $res = $database->questions;
$res->update({'person'=>'omer'},{'$set' => { 'canbeseen' =>"oha"}},{"multi" => "true"} );
```

i want to update all omer's "canbeseen"s.
but it isn't working, so how can i do that?
i'm waiting for your answers. thank you.

Comment: Please provide the code you've tried. What is `$res` and which module are you using?

Comment: i edited, now everything here.

Comment: What isn't working? Why don't you `use warnings`? What does `$database->last_error()` contain after the update?

Comment: I didn't get error. But it's only change one record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MongoDB module seems to use the `multiple` keyword instead of `multi`:

```
$res->update(
  {'person'   => 'omer' },
  {'$set'     => { 'canbeseen' => "oha" } },
  {'multiple' => "true" }
);
```

From the [documentation](http://search.cpan.org/dist/MongoDB/lib/MongoDB/Collection.pm):

> `multiple` All of the documents that match $criteria will be updated, not just the first document found. (Only available with database version 1.1.3 and newer.)